# What are the names of certain characters' children in the Hunger Games?

Tags: character-identification, the-hunger-games

> What are the names of Katniss's and Peeta's son and daughter?

I have read the books and watched the movies but I can't find the answer.

Answer (score 5):

### **The books don't say what their names were.**

Peeta and Katniss having children is mentioned in the epilogue on the final page of Mockingjay.

> They play in the Meadow. **The dancing girl with the dark hair and blue eyes. The boy with blond curls and gray eyes**, struggling to keep up with her on his chubby toddler legs. It took five, ten, fifteen years for me to agree. But Peeta wanted them so badly.

This is the only line in the books that references their children, but it never goes on further to mention what their names are. I don't recall their names being given in the films either, and I believe this to be so that fans can interpret the end of the story as they see fit, especially since the books were not especially clear on

> whether or not a Hunger Games ever takes place with the Capitol's children as a form of retribution for the Districts.

Comment: From what I can remember, I don't believe the films really touched on the two having children, although it's been a while since I watched Mockingjay. As far as the whole Capitol Hunger Games thing goes, I think the movie took a stronger stance on that than the book, but again, it has been forever and a half since I read or watched either of these.

Comment: there was a scene at the end of Mockingjay Part 2 with the children, Peeta, and Katniss; Pleiades

Answer (score -1):

yeah but a lot of people say the kids names are Willow and Rye but I have read lots of fanfictions with names like Rose, Prudence and Hunter (in my opinion I don't
like prudence very much as a name)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The question isn't what other people call them, or what names are used in fanfics.  Based on the books and the movies, what are their names (with references)?

Comment: There are no names. Names have never been provided anywhere except for for sketchy websites like this one saying they are Willow and Rye. It is pointless to ask  as Suzanne Collins doesn't appear to be revealing them anytime soon.

Comment: Its a topic of argument what everyone thinks the names are. Search the universe for answers and you will never get true ones. I have read the books and watched the end scene with the children and the children go unnamed and appear very differently in the books to the movies. I suggest looking up a few articles of this topic on the website Bustle to help you get a clearer understanding.